# efficiently get struct member with macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I am implementing double linked list. I produce the following macro, based on [linux kernel list](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h) and the macro [container_of](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/scripts/kconfig/list.h#L18):

```
typedef struct  s_list
{
    struct s_list   *prev;
    struct s_list   *next;
}               t_list;

# define LIST_ENTRY(ptr, type, lst_member) \
                (type*)((char*)ptr - offsetof(type, lst_member))

# define LIST_MEMBER(ptr, type, lst_member, member) \
                *(typeof(&(((type*)0)->member))) \
                    (LIST_ENTRY(ptr, type, lst_member) + offsetof(type, member))
```

I wonder how efficient are those macro. I would use `LIST_MEMBER()` by defining a new macro depending on my struct, for instance, for instance:

```
struct  test
{
     void    *ptr;
     t_list  lst;
     double  x;
};

# define TEST_LIST_C2(ptr) LIST_MEMBER(ptr, struct test, list, c2)
```

I have two questions:

- Everything except ptr is known at compile time. I would like to know if gcc would replace at compile time what he already knows so that my program just compute:

  ```
  *(double*)((char*)ptr + 24)
  ```
- Is there a more efficient way to access list content ?

Comment: Why do you wonder about efficiency? Did you identify a bottleneck? Do you have any measurements?

Comment: Not at all, I am just looking for good practice (or at least, avoid inefficient  preventable code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in C99 7.17.3 offsetof() is a macro, so it's evaluated at compile time. typeof() is a GNU extension, but it's also a macro. Macros are replaced with their values at compile time (the preprocessing phase).

So yes, gcc will compute everything it can at compile time and reduce the expression the way you expect.